# ...than I would have (done) otherwise

Tags: idiomatic-language

So you didn't see her every day?

No. I think I've seen her more the last three months than I would have (done) otherwise.

Is it idiomatic to omit *done* here?

Comment: You can discard the [predictable] "helper" verb ***done*** if you want. It's just a stylistic choice that has no semantic significance. Come to that, you could discard the "perfect" modifier verb ***have*** as well. All three versions are perfectly idiomatic, but I have no particular opinion or gut feel as to the relative prevalence of each variation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that your comment should be promoted to an answer. It looks good to me.

Comment: @PeterJennings: I used to always say such "optional" elements (***have done***, here) are ***predictably repeated*** (and therefore "deletable"), but in this particular case only ***have*** is present earlier in the text (in contracted ***I've***). I don't know how to describe what's going on syntactically with the helper verb ***done***, which *doesn't* occur earlier. So although I can say what's idiomatically acceptable, I *can't* really "explain" why things are the way they are.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To rapidly go off topic, yes, but does the OP really need a detailed technical answer involving the arcane recesses of English grammar or do they need to know if their sentence sounds like good English to native speakers like you and I? Plus any help we can provide to improve it even further, suggest alternatives etc. But these comments aren't the place for this discussion. and I don't want to get into an argument.